# Simple ASP.Net MVC 1.0 Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

On the current project we are working on we haven't upgraded to MVC 2.0 yet so I'm working on implementing some simple validation with the tools available in 1.0.

I'm looking for feedback on the way I'm doing this.

I have a model that represents a user profile. Inside that model I have a method that will validate all the fields and such. What I want to do is pass a controller to the validation method so that the model can set the model validation property in the controller. The goal is to get the validation from the controller into the model.

Here is a quick example

```
public FooController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Edit(User user)
     {
          user.ValidateModel(this);

          if (ModelState.IsValid)
               .......
               .......
      }
}
```

And my model validation signature is like

```
public void ValidateModel(Controller currentState)
```

What issues can you see with this? Am I way out to lunch on how I want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MVC 1.0 projects we do the following:

```
/* In model class */

public void Validate(string dealerId)
{
    ExceptionList exceptions = new ExceptionList();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.UserName))
    {
        exceptions.Exceptions.Add(new InvalidFieldException("Error message", "ContractType"));
    }

    ... other validations ...

    if (exceptions.Exceptions.Count > 0)
    {
        throw exceptions;
    }
}


/* In controller */

public virtual ActionResult UpdateProfile(User user)
{

    try
    {
        user.Validate();
    }
    catch (ExceptionList ex)
    {
        ex.CopyToModelState(ModelState);
    }
}


/* Custom types (ExceptionList / InvalidFieldException) */

[Serializable]
public class ExceptionList : Exception
{
    private List<Exception> exceptions;
    public List<Exception> Exceptions
    {
        get { return exceptions; }
        set { exceptions = value; }
    }

    public ExceptionList() { Init(); }
    public ExceptionList(string message) : base(message) { Init(); }
    public ExceptionList(string message,
        System.Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner) { Init(); }
    protected ExceptionList(
        System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
        System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { Init(); }


    private void Init()
    {
        Exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class InvalidFieldException : Exception
{
    private string fieldName;
    public string FieldName
    {
        get
        {
            return fieldName;
        }
        set
        {
            fieldName = value;
        }
    }

    private string fieldId;
    public string FieldId
    {
        get
        {
            return fieldId;
        }
        set
        {
            fieldId = value;
        }
    }

    public InvalidFieldException() { }
    public InvalidFieldException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public InvalidFieldException(string message, string fieldName)
        : base(message)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
    public InvalidFieldException(string message, string fieldName, string fieldId)
        : base(message)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldId = fieldId;
    }
    public InvalidFieldException(string message, System.Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner) { }
    public InvalidFieldException(string message, string fieldName,
        System.Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
    public InvalidFieldException(string message, string fieldName, string fieldId,
         System.Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldId = fieldId;
    }


    protected InvalidFieldException(
        System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
        System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
}


/* Extension method (to copy ExceptionList exceptions to ModelState) */

/// <summary>
/// Copies an ExceptionList to ModelState for MVC
/// </summary>
/// <param name="exList">List of exceptions</param>
/// <param name="modelState">Model state to populate</param>
/// <param name="collection">Form collection of data posted to the action</param>
/// <param name="prefix">Prefix used in view (if any)</param>
/// <param name="isCollection">Indicates whether a collection of objects are being returned from the view (requires prefix)</param>
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static void CopyToModelState(this ExceptionList exList, ModelStateDictionary modelState, FormCollection collection, string prefix, bool isCollection)
{
    foreach (InvalidFieldException ex in exList.Exceptions)
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
        {
            modelState.AddModelError(ex.FieldName, ex.Message);
            modelState.SetModelValue(ex.FieldName, collection.ToValueProvider()[ex.FieldName]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isCollection)
            {
                modelState.AddModelError(prefix + "[" + ex.FieldId + "]." + ex.FieldName, ex.Message);
                modelState.SetModelValue(prefix + "[" + ex.FieldId + "]." + ex.FieldName, collection.ToValueProvider()[ex.FieldName]);
            }
            else
            {
                modelState.AddModelError(prefix + "." + ex.FieldName, ex.Message);
                modelState.SetModelValue(prefix + "." + ex.FieldName, collection.ToValueProvider()[ex.FieldName]);
            }
        }
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies an ExceptionList to ModelState for MVC
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exList">List of exceptions</param>
    /// <param name="modelState">Model state to populate</param>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static void CopyToModelState(this ExceptionList exList, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        CopyToModelState(exList, modelState, null, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies an ExceptionList to ModelState for MVC
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exList">List of exceptions</param>
    /// <param name="modelState">Model state to populate</param>
    /// <param name="collection">Form collection of data posted to the action</param>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static void CopyToModelState(this ExceptionList exList, ModelStateDictionary modelState, FormCollection collection)
    {
        CopyToModelState(exList, modelState, collection, null, false);
    }
```

Basically, we're just throwing a group of exceptions back to the controller and letting the controller add them to ModelState. Pretty simple and modular.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I can see with this approach is that your validation logic is coupled to the controller. Actually the validator doesn't need the controller but only an `IDictionary<string, ModelState>` in order to set errors.

I would suggest you looking at the [fluent validation library](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which allows you to completely decouple your validation logic from the controller. It uses a model binder in which it has access to the controller in order to set errors.

So your action code will look like this:

```
public FooController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Edit(User user)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {

         }
         return View();
     }
}
```

Model errors are added during the binding. [Here's a nice article](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/06/fluentvalidation-1-2-beta-2-and-mvc2-rc2/) demonstrating the integration of this library with ASP.NET MVC. [Unit testing](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/08/19/asp-net-mvc-tdd-and-fluent-validation/) your validation logic is also very easy and readable.